# Flutter FlatButton is deprecated - alternative solution

Tags: flutter, dart, deprecated, flatbutton

This is my  FlatButton. How can I solve it with textButton or elevatedButton?

```
Center(
  child: FlatButton(
    onPressed: () {  },
    child: Container(
      margin:EdgeInsets.only(top: 25),
      child: image != null 
        ? Image.file(image,width:140,height:192,fit:BoxFit.fill) 
        : Container(
          width: 240, 
          height: 200, 
          child: Icon(Icons.camera_front, size: 100, color:Colors.grey,)
        ),
      ),
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change `FlatButton` to `TextButton` or `ElevatedButton`.

Answer (score 1):

Change FlatButton to TextButton.

```
Center(
  child: TextButton(
    onPressed: () {  },
    child: Container(
      margin:EdgeInsets.only(top: 25),
      child: image != null 
        ? Image.file(image,width:140,height:192,fit:BoxFit.fill) 
        : Container(
          width: 240, 
          height: 200, 
          child: Icon(Icons.camera_front, size: 100, color:Colors.grey,)
        ),
      ),
    ),
),
```

For styling using TextButton,

```
            TextButton(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                primary: Colors.white,
                textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
              child: const Text('Gradient'),
            ),
```

Answer (score 1):

FlatButton is replaced with TextButton and RaisedButton is replaced with ElevatedButton.

Here is the code of TextButton with styling

```
TextButton(
    onPressed: () {  },
    style: ButtonStyle(
      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.deepPurple)
    ),
    child: Container(
      margin:EdgeInsets.only(top: 25),
      child: image != null
          ? Image.file(image,width:140,height:192,fit:BoxFit.fill)
          : Container(
          width: 240,
          height: 200,
          child: Icon(Icons.camera_front, size: 100, color:Colors.grey,)
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a breaking change in the latest release of Flutter.

```
The FlatButton, RaisedButton and OutlineButton widgets have been 
replaced by TextButton, ElevatedButton, and OutlinedButton respectively.
```

Source:
https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons

See below table for comparison of old vs new button
https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons#context

And API details for changes at indvidual styling level.
https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons#api-change-buttonstyle-instead-of-individual-style-properties